# "WorkerProcessRestarting. Initialization timed out and host is shutting down" Azure function app run time error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

"WorkerProcessRestarting. Initialization timed out and host is shutting down" Azure function app run time error for Isolated function, can someone please help.

I created isolated function app in framework 4.8, not able to debug it locally or run it locally. Visual studio doesn't show any error when i try to debug the function app. It keeps processing without hitting the function and not returning any error.
Then I tried to deploy it Azure, deployment went fine, when i Try to Run it, get below error in 10 secs
"WorkerProcessRestarting. Initialization timed out and host is shutting down"

Answer (score 0):

- I have reproduced in my environment that VS 2022 is not working with the Azure Functions .NET 4.8 Isolated Project in both debug and running.
- Tried with the VS Code with the same project, it worked only for Run without debugging.
  [image]
- Debugger Points not hitting the code in VS Code and also in VS 2022:
  [image]

[image]

- I have raised the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1171)  in GitHub - Azure Functions dotnet worker Repository and will update the resolution here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes you are right it won't work with VS2022 I upgraded to 'Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Preview'.
In my case I made a silly mistake which I fixed this morning and everything is working as expected. I'll add it in the section below, hopefully will help somebody else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Microsoft sample for Isolated Function App
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/tree/main/samples/FunctionApp

In my case , by mistake I removed this line *.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults*

[This is the screenshot of the Program.cs from the url above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9q5c.png)

This is what I added to Program.cs in my solution and which fixed the issue for me.
[Program.cs with minimum code to make it work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dLqe.png)